# Uncheck call to Add(e) as a member of Rawtype Java.util.arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I always get a warning and don't know how to solve this. It would be interesting what possibly could happen if i leave this unsolved.

```
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Motivation
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Tips
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Health
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Toxic Information
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // Statistics
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    // Settings
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
```

This is the relevant part of the code where i get those warnings.

Comment: Can you show how you are declaring the variable navDrawerItems

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4303555/3998458) could help you.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Just on top with "protected ArrayList navDrawerItems;" Alexandro: Already found that link, but didn't helped me a lot.